# Can my neighbor's hear what is coming out of my speakers

Tags: audio, speakers, crossover

So this morning I clearly heard my neighbor's baby, through their monitor I am assuming, through my speakers (Logitech - Z313 Multimedia Speaker System).  Now I thought this was odd since my speakers are wired not wireless.

But my question is, is it possible that what ever comes out of my speakers can be picked up by their baby monitor?

Comment: I remember the late 70's, rock gigs, where the local taxi company would suddenly replace the lead vocalist, loud & proud to the entire audience... No, it's not 2-way, it's RFI [radio frequency interference]. Tell your neighbours they need a new baby monitor, one with encrypted WiFi rather than analog taxi frequencies ;-) The actual problem is two-fold - their interference & your lack of signal rejection.

Comment: so I don't know if you were being tongue and cheek but is there anything I can do to shield my speakers from the signal

Comment: I was kind of joking, but in actual fact, there was nothing inaccurate in what I said. The joke was merely the way I said it. Taxi radio did used to break through to rock gigs in the 70s. Your neighbours' monitor is producing similar signals. In this day & age of signal-intercept paranoia, no-one should still be using AM radio 'walkie talkies'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your neighbor's baby monitor is transmitting audio via radio waves, essentially like a walky-talky. It is possible that these radio waves are inducing a current on your speaker wire, causing you to hear that audio out your speakers. You should be able to eliminate that interference by installing a ferrite core on your speaker wire: [Ferrite Core 1/2 Cord Noise Suppressor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002MQGEK).

Because your system is not wireless it is highly unlikely that anybody would be able to hear the audio being played from your computer without some sophisticated eavesdropping equipment. Any time current is oscillated on a wire, as it is over a speaker wire, some amount of electro magnetic energy is radiated, but in the case of computer speakers this energy should be extremely low power, so there is really no need to worry about it being picked up unintentionally. Shielding speaker wires (by covering the wire in a grounded sheath) would eliminate this radiated electromagnetic energy, but it also apparently increases the capacitance of the wire, which isn't good for your sound quality, so it is generally discouraged.

Comment: Poorly built computer speakers are notorious for picking up stray radio signals.  At my workplace, I've frequently heard them picking up local FM radio stations.

Comment: @CharlesBurge -*"I've frequently heard them picking up local FM radio stations"* -- Not likely, it's AM radio stations that causes problems.

Comment: I'm generally with you on all that - but the RFI has to be *before* any amplification, rather than after it, otherwise it would be too quiet to ever be heard. So, it's either that the speakers are themselves internally amped, or even equipment prior to that that's the source [or rather receptor] of the interference.